# How to show the content after modifying the URL without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, google-chrome, url

I am modifying the URL without reloading the page using
`window.history.pushState("string", "title", "/new-url");`
but when I tried to access the new changed URL in a new tab the content does not show up, it throws an error `Cannot GET /new-url`. How to show the content in the new URL?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), history.pushState only adds an entry to the browser's session history stack. It does not trigger a page reload.

In traditional server-side rendered apps, each change of the URL triggered a request towards the backend for the new page.

In today's single-page applications (SPA), a browser router shows different content on the page based on the URL, without reloading the whole page. If you want to play around with a SPA and a browser router, I would recommend a [React](https://reactjs.org/) library and [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) as an example of a browser router.

Since I do not know exactly what tech stack you are working with, I can't give you a specific answer, but if you are trying to access `someHost/new-url` and the server is telling you that it doesn't exist, then you need to create a resource on that URL before you try to GET it.

Comment: yeah i understand ..i am trying to access a URL which does not exist..